# How to build AutoMapper source?

Tags: msbuild, automapper

AutoMapper v3.2.1 has many targets  (silverlight, WinRT, etc).  The solution does not load correctly in visual studio 2013 because I do not have all the tools the projects require (and on windows 7).  In MSBuild I tried:

```
msbuild AutoMapper.sln /P:Configuration=Release
```

However over 100 errors are thrown related to these projects I don't care about.  I just need to target .NET 4 for a C# console application.

Comment: There is a .NET 4.0 assembly in the NuGet package already.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - Yes, but I am not going to use NuGet, want the source to build.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this myself. Apparently you need VS2015 to build it. It uses new C# 6 compiler features.